# How to find how many shops account for 5% of sales

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

Suppose I have a table where one column is "Shop Address" and another column is "Sales". I want to have a table that shows:

- 5% of total sales are generated by the top X1 shops
- 10% of total sales are generated by the top X2 shops
- 15% of total sales are generated by the top X3 shops
- 20% of total sales are generated by the top X4 shops
  ... etc

How would I do this? It sounds simple, but I can't think of how to do it.

Comment: You need to decide on a formula you want to use first. It's a math and not an excel problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach. Let's assume that you have a list of 25 stores in cells `B2:B26` and their sales in cells `C2:C26`.

Start by sorting the combined range `B2:C26` by sales (column B) in descending order.

Add a third column for the cumulative percent of sales for the sorted list of stores. The formula for the first cell, `D2`, will be:

```
  =SUM($C$2:C2)/SUM($C$2:$C$26)
```

Drag the formula down through cell `D26`, which should equal 100 percent. The resulting table might look something like this:

[image]

The result table will also have two columns, one for the break points you specified - 5%, 10%, 15% and 20% - and one for the formulas that will count the number of stores.

Note that if you have a small number of stores, like the 25 in this example, you could just eyeball the list to get the counts and call it quits.T The benefit of having formulas do the count is that they will make it easy to get the counts if you have a lot of stores or a lot of breakpoints.

Trying to pin down an exact formula to count the stores raises an interesting question. How do you want to treat the situation where the cumulative sales don't fall neatly into the bins you've specified? If one store accounts for 4.9% of sales, it seems reasonable to say that 1 store produced 5 percent of sales. But what if the one store accounted for only 3.6% of sales, with a second store bringing in 3.2% of sales. So, was it one store or two stores responsible for 5% of sales?

For the 1 store count in that situation, you would use the following formula (assuming the result table's list of percentage breakpoints began in cell `F2`):

```
  =COUNTIF($D$2:$D$21,"<="&F2)
```

Copying this formula down produces the following result table for the example data:

[image: result table]

If you wanted to get the (hypothetical) two store count, the formula for the result table would be:

```
  =COUNTIF($D$2:$D$21,"<="&I2)+IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(I2,$D$2:$D$21,1,0)),1,0)
```

This has an added term that counts the additional store needed to bring cumulative sales up to exactly the percentage breakpoint.

[image: alternative result table]

Comment: Thanks! Good work. Also, nice greyhound/whippet avatar. I looove those dogs sooo much!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you're asking for, but you can determine the percentage each store contributes to the total sale by taking each store's sales and dividing it by the total sales of all the stores.  A sample formula might look like this:

```
=B2/SUM($B$2:$B10)
```

This assumes your sales are in column `B` and go down as far as row 10. The `$` will allow you to drag the formula down without changing the sum totals.  Either format this number as a percentage, or multiply by 100 to get the percent equivalent.  From here you can pick out which ones meet your 5%, 10%, etc, criteria.

Comment: Thank you Tech Turtle. Your suggestion seems like a good starting point. I clarified my question a little.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a VBA user defined function that will achieve the same thing. It does the following:

1) Takes a vertical range of numbers, and copies them into an array. Depending on the argument "sign" it will either discard negatives, discard positives, or take positives and negatives.

2) Gets another function to sort the array from smallest to largest (not provided).

3) Iterates across the array from biggest to smallest while summing each element to find how many are needed to make up X%.

Caution: Because of the rounding I use, I suspect it wouldn't work when dealing with very small numbers.

```
Function ProjectsInPercent(FromRange As Range, TopPercent As Double, sign As Integer) As Double
    Dim values()  As Variant 'array to hold values
    Dim row As Integer
    Dim sum As Double
    Dim percentOfSum As Double
    Dim tmpVal As Double
    sum = 0

ReDim values(1 To FromRange.rows.Count)

If (FromRange.rows.Count > UBound(values, 1)) Then
    ProjectsInPercent = "Too many rows in range"
ElseIf (TopPercent < 0 Or TopPercent > 1) Then
    ProjectsInPercent = "Percentile should be between 0 and 1"
End If

For row = 1 To UBound(values, 1)
    tmpVal = FromRange.Cells(row, 1).value
    If IsNumeric(tmpVal) Then
        If sign > 0 Then
            tmpVal = IIf(tmpVal > 0, tmpVal, 0)
        ElseIf sign < 0 Then
            tmpVal = IIf(tmpVal < 0, -tmpVal, 0)
        End If
        sum = sum + tmpVal
        values(row) = tmpVal
    Else
        values(row) = 0
    End If
Next row

Call QuickSort(values, 1, UBound(values, 1))

percentOfSum = sum * TopPercent
sum = 0
For row = 1 To UBound(values, 1)
    tmpVal = values(UBound(values, 1) - row + 1)
    If Round(sum + tmpVal, 1) >= Round(percentOfSum, 1) Then
        ProjectsInPercent = row + (percentOfSum - sum - tmpVal) / tmpVal
        Exit For
    End If
    sum = sum + tmpVal
Next row

End Function
```